# Detect static file request from .NET core middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I'm writing some middleware to parse the sub-domain of a given request URL to determine the website theme.  I want to ignore static file requests in order to reduce unnecessary database lookups, and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var staticFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".css", ".js", ".png", ".ico" };
if (staticFileExtensions.Any(x => httpContext.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(x)))
{
    await _next(httpContext);
}
else
{
    var hostParts = httpContext.Request.Host.Host.Split('.').ToList();
    if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/healthcheck"))
    || (hostParts.Count == 6 && _whitelistedDomains.Contains(hostParts[0])))
    {
        httpContext.Items.Add("account", hostParts[0]);
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
    else
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
}
```

This is where I've added it to Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseDomainWhitelisting();
```

It feels as though there should be a cleaner way to detect which requests to ignore, or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use conditional middleware based on request.
Something like:

```
app.UseMiddlewareOne();

app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddlewareTwo();
});

app.UseMiddlewareThree();
```

Source:
https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to.

Any middleware that is registered AFTER the call to `UseStaticFiles` will not execute, if the request ended up serving a static file.

I just verified this behavior on .NET 6 and 7 under both IIS and Kestrel hosting on both Windows and Linux.

That's probably because the static-files middleware never calls `_next(context)` delegate, thus aborting the whole pipeline. This is called ***terminal middleware*** because it ***short circuits*** a request. I wish MS docs mentioned it somewhere, but we can always look at the source codes...

Aaaah-nd yep, just as I thought, source code confirms this: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/StaticFileMiddleware.cs,79

P.S. In other words, to solve the OP's problem - just make sure you call `UseStaticFiles` ***before*** executing your domain logic middleware. Also make sure the file actually exists. If not - the app will proceed to next middleware.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite old question but I cam to it when I had similar problem,
I could solve the issue and determine static files request by checking if request is ended with extension.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(httpContext.Request.Path)))
 //this is normal request
else
 //this can be a file as it ends with some extension (ex*.png)
```